# How do I make a Firebase Form?

Tags: forms, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for a website page. How would I create a form with Firebase? And the data be stored in a database? There doesn't seem to be any good tutorials out there. I am new to Firebase.

Answer (score 10):

Firebase database is more like a storage for your data objects. So all you need is build a JavaScript object from the form values and send to Firebase on submit.

Check this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/quinnkap/pen/EaedPm). Focus on the New Activity section. You will see how you can build objects from your form values and send to Firebase.

For instance, you have a form in your html:

```
<form id='myForm'>
  <input id='title' type='text' />
  <input id='description' type='text' />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

And in your JavaScript file you can do this:

```
// Listen to the form submit event
$('#myForm').submit(function(evt) {

  // Target the form elements by their ids
  // And build the form object like this using jQuery: 
  var formData = {
    "title": $('#title').val(),
    "description": $('#description).val(),
  }

  evt.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default form submit action
  
  // You have formData here and can do this:
  firebase.initializeApp(config); //Initialize your firebase here passing your firebase account config object
  firebase.database().ref('/formDataTree').push( formData ); // Adds the new form data to the list under formDataTree node
})
```

Hope this helps