# Unity WebGL form posts to Cloud Firestore with Firebase JS SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My goal is to build a WebGL game in Unity that has a specific form and upon submission that form posts data into one of the Firebase storage solutions. After reading [this article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/cloud-firestore-for-rtdb-developers.html), it's clear to me I need to use Cloud Firestore instead of Realtime Database. Good news is that as of of March 2020, [one of the team members wrote](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/381#issuecomment-595845307),

> we released Firebase Unity SDK 6.12.0 which includes an alpha release
> of Firestore.

Thing is, Firebase's Unity SDK isn't for WebGL builds and, for someone going through that thought process, could use [Firebase JS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60883058/5675325) (spam alert). From looking at the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js), one can see that Firebase JS SDK supports Firestore and so this has all the conditions in place for a quick solution.

So, I've gone to Firebase console, created a project, a Web app to use Firebase JS SDK and this process gave as output the following code

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

with a message saying

> Copy and paste these scripts into the bottom of your  tag, but
> before you use any Firebase services

In addition to that, this is [how to Call JavaScript functions from Unity scripts](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) and this is a [Cloud Firestore JS Sample App](https://github.com/tiago-peres/quickstart-js/tree/master/firestore).

Given this information, how can then the form be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want a form that receives as input

- String
- Number
- Text from the user

In your Firestore console, create a collection and give it a name (like **formDataTree**), give an autoID and add the fields

- strVal
- intVal
- webVal

[image: Cloud Firestore create collection]

Then, I would put those scripts at the bottom of the head tag in your [WebGL template](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-templates.html). So, create a folder in Assets named **WebGLTemplates**, and a folder named New Template (or whatever name you will) and add an **index.html** there.

[image: New WebGL Template in Unity]

According to the documentation, this index.html should be similar to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | %UNITY_WEB_NAME%</title>
    <script src="%UNITY_WEBGL_LOADER_URL%"></script>
    <script>
    var unityInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("unityContainer", "%UNITY_WEBGL_BUILD_URL%");
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="unityContainer" style="width: %UNITY_WIDTH%px; height: %UNITY_HEIGHT%px; margin: auto"></div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

So, with this new information, it'll be something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | %UNITY_WEB_NAME%</title>
    <script src="%UNITY_WEBGL_LOADER_URL%"></script>
    <script>
        var unityInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("unityContainer", "%UNITY_WEBGL_BUILD_URL%");
    </script>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
         https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

    <script>
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        appId: "",
        measurementId: ""
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.analytics();
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="unityContainer" style="width: %UNITY_WIDTH%px; height: %UNITY_HEIGHT%px; margin: auto"></div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Then, under Player settings, select that template.

[image: Player WebGL Template]

Then in the body of the template, have a form with its visibility to hidden. Include things from the game as well as any inputs you want filled out in the browser:

```html
<form id="webForm" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <input type="hidden" id="stringInput" name="stringInput">
    <input type="hidden" id="intInput" name="intInput">
    <label for="webInput">web input</label><input type="text" id="webInput" name="webInput">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then below the Firebase script and the form, include a submit listener for the form on the page which will submit it to Firestore (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41305458/1092820)):

```
myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default form submit action

  var strVal = myForm.stringInput.value;
  var intVal = myForm.intInput.value;
  var webVal = intInput.webInput.value;

  var formData = {
    "strVal" : strVal,
    "intVal" : intVal,
    "webVal" : webVal
  };

  firebase.database().ref('/formDataTree').push( formData ); // Adds the new form data to the list under formDataTree node
});
```

All in all, the **index.html** should be something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Change Mapping | %UNITY_WEB_NAME%</title>
    <script src="%UNITY_WEBGL_LOADER_URL%"></script>
    <script>
        var unityInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("unityContainer", "%UNITY_WEBGL_BUILD_URL%");
    </script>
    
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
         https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

    <script>
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: "",
        appId: "",
        measurementId: ""
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.analytics();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="height:20px; width: %UNITY_WIDTH%px; background: green;" onclick="unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1)"><b>Click here to make it full screen.</b></div>
    <div id="unityContainer" style="width: %UNITY_WIDTH%px; height: %UNITY_HEIGHT%px; margin: auto"></div>
    <form id="webForm" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <input type="hidden" id="stringInput" name="stringInput">
        <input type="hidden" id="intInput" name="intInput">
        <label for="webInput">web input</label><input type="text" id="webInput" name="webInput">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        var myForm = document.getElementById("webForm");
        myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
          evt.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default form submit action

          var strVal = myForm.stringInput.value;
          var intVal = myForm.intInput.value;
          var webVal = intInput.webInput.value;

          var formData = {
            "strVal" : strVal,
            "intVal" : intVal,
            "webVal" : webVal
          };

          firebase.database().ref('/formDataTree').push( formData ); // Adds the new form data to the list under formDataTree node
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using the apiKey, authDomain, etc in the template it means that it will show up when inspecting the page or viewing page source as. Yet, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484053/5675325), it's ok to share that information.

Then, in your Assets folder, create a **Plugins** folder and add to it a `.jslib` file, for instances named **form.jslib**, that has a function that shows the form, and puts game data into the form's hidden inputs.

[image: Plugins in Asset]

```js
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  ShowWebForm: function (importantString, importantInt) {
    var myForm = document.getElementById("webForm");

    myForm.stringInput.value = Pointer_stringify(importantString);
    myForm.intInput.value = importantInt;

    myForm.style.visibility="visible"
   
  },
});
```

After the steps up to this point, if you get in the console `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`, simply deactivate AdBlocker for that site as [that's why you get that error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23352822/5675325).

Finally, in Unity, declare that function and call it when appropriate. So, considering you have a newly created scene (so it only has Main Camera and Directional Light), you could call that method in some code that gets called in the new scene. It's a static method so as long as you can find the data you need for the parameters you can call it from anywhere.

```cs
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void ShowWebForm(string importantString, int importantInt);

public void Start()
{
    // Suppose we want to send the version of unity the app is running on 
    // and the unix timestamp at start
    string unityVersion = Application.unityVersion;

    System.DateTime epochStart = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,  
            System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    int cur_time = (int)(System.DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart).TotalSeconds;

    ShowWebForm(unityVersion, cur_time);
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to have the user fill things out in the browser, you can leave the form invisible and instead of setting it to visible, dispatch a submit event:

```js
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  ShowWebForm: function (importantString, importantInt) {
    var myForm = document.getElementById("webForm");

    myForm.stringInput.value = Pointer_stringify(importantString);
    myForm.intInput.value = importantInt;
    myForm.webInput.value = "some other value from the game could go here";

    myForm.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));
  },
});
```

Can't test at the moment, so be aware of typos or other syntax errors.

Comment: Would you be ok with having `apiKey: "", authDomain: "", databaseURL: "",` in that template? It will show up when inspecting the page or viewing page source.

Comment: Also, what do you mean with `Finally, in Unity, declare that function and call it when appropriate.` assuming we just created a new Scene (so it only has Main Camera and Directional Light)?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 hmm, I'm not familiar with firebase but I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484053/1092820) which makes it seem like these can be safely exposed. As for he new scene question, I would suppose you could call that method in some code that gets called in the new scene. It's a static method so as long as you can find the data you need for the parameters you can call it from anywhere. Thanks for improving my answer also!

Comment: Thank you for your help up to this point. The answer is getting very good and I haven't seen such thing up to this point yet anywhere. Still, I'm not visualizing the last part Ruzihm. If you will, a more specific case of its usage would help to improve the answer.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 Thank you again for the improvements you are contributing. I hope my latest edit helps.